# how do I set up wifi on dietPI?

Tags: networking, wifi, debian

I just got a "TimeHat" (gps shield, + real time clock) (its working great over 60 satellites instantly ) DietPI is the OS it shipped with, which has the hardware preconfigured. I am using a Raspberry Pi 4. I would like to configure wifi though.
I tried running `dietpi-wifidb` which had me setup my wireless credentials, it scanned, and found my network, and then I entered the encryption type, and passphrase.
unfortunately I was still not connected to the network. dietpi is pretty stripped down, its missing loads of what I would consider useful programs, like vi, less, ifconfig/iwconfig, etc... I'm not sure I can get any more meaningful info to share.

dietPi is a debian based distro, aarch64, buster, running kernel 5.10.17

Comment: does dietpi come with `/sbin/ip` (i.e. the uproute2 package) - if so, what's the output of `ip a show dev wlan0`

Comment: admittedly I am very new to the operation of diet-pi. I have rebooted, and now the networks I added are connected.  so problem solved.